# Recover files with deleted indexes by chkdsk from corrupt NTFS volume?

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery, chkdsk, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery

First off, I realize similar questions have been asked before, but most of them don't actually have any answers from what I've found. I'm hoping that perhaps there might be an actual answer out there that has not been covered yet.

I have an external hard drive that is clearly failing. I had it connected earlier to begin copying files off of it, which was going fine.  I had to leave for a bit and when I came back to wake my computer, the drive failed to remount with an error saying the filesystem was corrupt. Now to attempt to get it to mount again, I tried running `chkdsk /F` on it. I had no clue that `chkdsk /F` would potentially start deleting file indexes on the disk, but that's what started to happen. I stopped it before it removed any more of the indexes, but now it would seem I've lost those several hundred files it did manage to remove indexes for. I'm running PhotoRec on the volume now to see if it can manage to scrape anything up, but I'm not holding my breath.

Am I entirely out of luck, or is there *anything* at all I can possibly do to get some of these files back?

Also, yes, I know that additional backups should have been made, but I honestly couldn't afford additional drives at this point in time.

Comment: The removal of the indexies means the file system lost track of your files, even if you had not ran chkdsk the chances your files were corrupt are very high

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I was afraid of... It's just so crazy to think that it could have degraded that far in the spam of the couple hours I was gone. I had been copying files off, one folder at a time, without issue. I assume there is no existing way to even try to recover those files, now that the indexes are gone?

Comment: You are talking about directory indexes like `$INDEX_ROOT` and `$INDEX_ALLOCATION`, right? Then your files are not lost at all and **can** be recovered. But do not try again to ruin it with `chkdsk` in the meantime.

Comment: I'm talking about when chkdsk ran, it spewed hundreds of lines like `Deleting index entry file.txt in index $I30 of file 12345`